# Magento - How much external traffic can Magento handle?

Tags: php, web-services, rest, magento

We are in the process of developing an application on top of Magento where we will be using the default Magento products and listing related functionalities and customer related functionalities.

But for the app we're developing, we need to have data synchronized from an external database to Magento, 'real-time'. We are handling this through event triggers from the external application and by exposing custom REST APIs in Magento to consume the data. We do have a separate database on the same server other than Magento's to have the custom tables replicated from the external source.

Now the question here is, how does the REST APIs built on Magento behave when there is a huge number of data coming in back to back? All we're doing is to read the incoming data and insert/update/delete it into/into/from the appropriate tables. It is crucial to not to miss any data that comes in.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on the configuration and resources of your server. The code quality of the 3rd-party and your extensions is also important. The best solution is made a stress test on your application/system.